# Passing Value Betweeen Functions jQuery Ajax and Replace Null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting the value from a dropdownlist into the following function and it works if the value is not Null. I then want to pass this value to the next function.

So 2 parts how do I replace the null value with a static value "asc" in this function

```
   function getdropdownlistSelectedItem(sender, args) {
    var raddropdownlist = $find('<%=RadDropDownList1.ClientID %>');
    var selecteditem = raddropdownlist.get_selectedItem().get_value();
    alert(selecteditem);
}
```

Then pass the value of selecteditem to the following var sortby in this function

I was trying var sortby = getdropdownlistSelectedItem()

```
      function GetRecords() {
    var sortby = getdropdownlistSelectedItem();
    alert('Sortby: ' + sortby);
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "categorypage.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', sortby: ' + sortby + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can correct this for me

Comment: Which value is null?

Comment: the value from the dropdown list is null on initial pageload. ie if it hasn't been selected. so the value of selecteditem could be null and need replacing with a default of asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have the `getDropDownListSelectedItem()` function return either the value of the dropdown list or "abc", whichever is not `null` (no variable even needed to store result) using the Boolean logical "OR" operator.

This will check the first operand (`raddropdownlist.get_selectedItem().get_value()`) for a "truthy" value (anything that converts to `true` when converted to a Boolean). If that call returns `null` (which is "falsely"), then the second operand (`"abc"`) is checked for "truthy" (which it is, so it is returned).

```
function getdropdownlistSelectedItem(sender, args) {
    var raddropdownlist = $find('<%=RadDropDownList1.ClientID %>');

    // Function will return result of .get_value() or "abc" 
    // in the case of .get_value() returning null:
    return raddropdownlist.get_selectedItem().get_value() || "abc";
}
```

After making this change, `var sortby = getdropdownlistSelectedItem();` in `GetRecords()` will have either the value of the drop down or `abc`.

Here's a scaled down example that shows how this works in action:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", GetRecord);

function getdropdownlistSelectedItem(sender, args) {
   var raddropdownlist = document.querySelector("select");

   // Function will return result of .get_value() or "abc" 
   // in the case of .get_value() returning null:
   return raddropdownlist.value || "abc";
}

function GetRecord(){
  console.log(getdropdownlistSelectedItem());  
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Choose Me For A null value</option>
  <option>Non-null Value 1</option>
  <option>Non-null Value 2</option>
  <option>Non-null Value 3</option>  
</select>
<button type="button">Get drop down list value</button>
```

Comment: thanks you change has worked for me although I'm still getting an undefined alert message which must be from something else. Can I ask am I passing the param in the data correctly data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', sortby: ' + sortby + '}',

Comment: @jasonkkt It looks OK as a JSON string or it could be: `data: "pageIndex=" + pageIndex + '&sortby=' + sortby` if you want to pass a string.

Comment: thanks for your support something else must be causing the undefined error. I'll try and find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters (sender, args) to the second function (GetRecords()) instead. Then call the first function within the second function. 
Note that the first function is returning selecteditem. Hope it helps!

```
function getdropdownlistSelectedItem(sender, args) {
    var raddropdownlist = $find('<%=RadDropDownList1.ClientID %>');
    var selecteditem = raddropdownlist.get_selectedItem().get_value();
    //alert(selecteditem);
    if(selecteditem == null) selecteditem = 'asc';
    return selecteditem;
}


function GetRecords(sender, args) {
    var sortby = getdropdownlistSelectedItem(sender, args);
    alert('Sortby: ' + sortby);
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "categorypage.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', sortby: ' + sortby + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add *return* statement to your *getdropdownlistSelectedItem()* function and check whether *selecteditem* is null or undefined

```
if (selecteditem == null){
   return "abc"
}
return selecteditem
```

> Because **`null == undefined`** is **`true`**, the above code will catch both null
>   and undefined.